# How to achieve this custom number picker?

Tags: android, datepicker, numberpicker

Im trying to make something like this

[This is what i wanna achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chnS0.jpg)
How do you achieve the second value and the third value picker ?
Do i need to change to datepicker ?

*EDIT

for the second value i tried this method :

```
private String[] getDatesFromCalender() {
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+7"));
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+7"));

    List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE, dd MMM", new Locale("en", "Singapore"));
    dates.add(dateFormat.format(c1.getTime()));

    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        c1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        dates.add(dateFormat.format(c1.getTime()));
    }
    c2.add(Calendar.DATE, -60);

    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        c2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        dates.add(dateFormat.format(c2.getTime()));
    }
    return dates.toArray(new String[dates.size() - 1]);
}
```

then i put this on onCreate

```
 date = getDatesFromCalender();
```

and set the numberpicker

```
 private void setUpDatePicker() {
    npBookingDate.setDisplayedValues(date);
    npBookingDate.setMaxValue(date.length - 1);
    npBookingDate.setMinValue(0);
    npBookingDate.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
        @Override
        public String format(int value) {
            return date[value];
        }
    });
}
```

The result is what i wanted to but it add another date before today check the pict:
[Here is what i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKUPj.jpg)
How to disable dates before today dates ?

Answer (score 0):

OK , for showing two number picker in same dialog, i will post a code snippet as shown below

```
LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
//
final NumberPicker aNumberPicker = new NumberPicker(mContext);
aNumberPicker.setMaxValue(50);
aNumberPicker.setMinValue(1);
//
final NumberPicker aNumberPickerA = new NumberPicker(mContext);
aNumberPickerA.setMaxValue(11);
aNumberPickerA.setMinValue(1);
aNumberPickerA.setDisplayedValues(new String[] { "Tea Cup", "Glass","Plate","Small Plate","Cutlets","Medium","Piece","Katori","Balls","Serving","egg"});
//
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
//
LinearLayout.LayoutParams numPicerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
numPicerParams.weight = 1;
//
LinearLayout.LayoutParams qPicerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
qPicerParams.weight = 1;
//
LL.setLayoutParams(params);
LL.addView(aNumberPicker,numPicerParams);
LL.addView(aNumberPickerA,qPicerParams);
```

so , for three number picker, you can add one more number picker view inside the linear layout and attach this view to the dialog fragment, and you can achieve the funtionality

Comment: i think i can achieve the functionality fine with numberpicker.. what i wanna achieve is how do you get the second and third value picker